# Why is the degree of the zero polynomial not infinity?

Tags: polynomials

I understand that we do not want to say that the degree of the zero polynomial is zero, since deg($pq$) = deg($p$) + deg($q$), but this does not convince me that negative infinity is a better choice than infinity for the degree of the zero polynomial.

Is it because the zero polynomial still needs to have a lower degree than non-zero, non-constant polynomials? Or are there other reasons?

Comment: How about "undefined" instead of negative infinity? Does that work for you?

Comment: A lot of proofs work by inducting on the degree, which would be ruined (or at least have more complicated bookkeeping) in that case.

Comment: You'll find some authors saying that $0$ has no degree and some other autors saying that $0$ has degree $-\infty$. The convetion $\deg 0=-\infty$ preserves both inequalities $\deg(pq)=\deg p+\deg q$ and $\deg(p+q)\le \max\{\deg p,\deg q\}$. If you use the convention of not defining $\deg 0$ (I remember this having some upside to it, but I can't recall which was), then those inequalities are meant to hold for $p,q\ne 0$. I don't see $\deg 0=\infty$ having any upside.

Answer (score 4):

You also have $deg(p+q)\leq \max\{\deg(p),\deg(q)\}$ and $\deg(0+p)=\deg(p)$.

Comment: Should be $\deg (p+q)\le \max\{\deg p,\deg q\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the norm $N(p)$ of a polynomial $p$ by
$$
N(p)
=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $p = 0$}\\
2^{\deg(p)} & \text{if $p \ne 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
you will get a function which satisfies $N(p q) = N(p) N(q)$ for all polynomials $p, q$. This will allow you, for instance, to state polynomial division (over a field) as

> Given polynomials $a, b$, with $b \ne 0$, there exist polynomials $q, r$ such that
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> a = b q + r\\
> N(r) < N(b)
> \end{cases}
> $$

with no need to distinguish the case when $r = 0$. Clearly this is suggestive of the zero polynomial having degree $- \infty$. If you can handle this properly, this is ok, otherwise you can use this norm.